# Modal Loading message while script executes

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, modal-dialog, datatables

I have tried several methods to solve this but have been unable to get a work around.

basically I have a large data table that is being given to the DOM by Java, as the page loads the data table loads but then is parsed by an external script (DataTables @ datatables.net) that styles and adds functionality to the grid.  The problem is that the table shows up on the page un-styled and without the functions of the data tables script then disappears and reloads once the script is done executing.

What I want to do is hide the all the content on the page via jQuery on the page load then show it once the script executes and then close a modal loading dialog.

My question is: Is there a way to run a loading message via a modal until all scripts have executed.  The data in the table is pretty large (2000 records) and takes some time to compile....

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Could you show/hide something like this: http://jquery.malsup.com/block/ via callbacks for the datatable?

Answer (score 0):

What I would try to do is load the datatable into a hidden element like a

```
<div style="display:none">
     Put datatable here.
</div>
```

Show the modal that says loading(not with javascript, it should already be part of the DOM and visible), and in the callback for whatever JS is doing the work I would do something like this:

```
function myCallBack()
{
     $('#loadingModal').hide();
     $('#dataTableDiv').show();
}
```

Comment: The trouble with this is the page won't load until all the data is there, so the modal won't start to show until the page has loaded, which would show the loaded table anyway

Comment: You don't load the modal with javascript.  Its just there already.  You use JS to hide it when you are ready.  Changed my answer to be more clear.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I could think of doing this would be to load the data and everything for it via ajax. That way, you can load a very quick page with not much on it and show the loading modal dialogue, the begin your ajax for the table which would send a response once finished that you could use to close the dialogue